# are there any performance differences between vs 2008 and vs 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

is there any major performance changes in 2010.

Comment: I'd suggest to just try it out, either with the Trials or with the Express editions (the latter can be switched to Expert mode, offering a lot more than visible at first). This way, you can check specifically for your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a lot of complaints about perf during the beta cycle.  They even delayed the RTM release date by a few weeks to buy extra time to work on it.  It sure looked like cloudy with a chance of meat balls to me, but I've got the Ultimate edition running on two machines that also have VS2008 and they both are *very* responsive.  Many of the awkward delays in VS2008 are gone.  It is all around snappy.  Only starting the debugger seems a bit slower.

They did a great job, it is a fine product.  You won't be disappointed.  Defrag your hard drive before you install it.

Comment: I was also under the expression that the Release version is a lot more responsive than the Betas. On the other hand, I tried the Betas in a VM, the Release version on my host system, so the difference is a lot larger for me :) Any experience in a VM with the Release?